# How can I find a wifi password saved in Windows?

Tags: wireless-networking, passwords, password-recovery

I've just moved and the people, who've moved into my old apartment need the wifi password. It's saved somewhere in Windows 7, but I don't know, where exactly? Please help me find it.

Comment: Do you mean the password for wireless connections which is defined in the router?

Comment: Sounds like it would be easier for them to reset the router and start fresh, even more so if there's a physical reset key on the router. Without more detail (*or considering the question, perhaps even with*), it is unlikely anyone will be able to answer the question asked.

Comment: Usually there is toothpick hole in the back of the router, and using a toothpick you can reset it to the factory settings. The factory settings are printed on the label on the router. Usually it is user for user and administrator for password.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) to recover the passwords which Windows has saved. However, I think it would be easier for the people who have moved into your old appartment to reset the router, like the comments have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 7, you can view the key without any additional software.

1. Go to the **Network and Sharing Center** (Start->Type "network" and choose the option)
2. Click on **Manage Wireless Networks** on the left
3. Double click on the network profile to bring up its Properties
4. Click on the **Security** tab, then choose the tick box to reveal the saved password in plain text